# Is it possible to provide JSON Array as data to dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore

Tags: json, dojo

I have JSON array like 
[
["jhon", "newyork", "9999"],
["bob", "chicago", "5555"],
["rolf", "germany", "1111"]
]

and i want to provide this JSON Array to dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore.

IS it possible to send this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to feed a JavaScript object directly as data to an ItemFileReadStore instance via the `data` attribute (alternatively to via `url`), but it's important to understand that whether you're providing the data directly or via XHR, your data will still need to conform to the format that ItemFileReadStore expects.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#input-data-format

There's actually an example further down the same page that shows an ItemFileReadStore being instantiated with an object being fed directly via the `data` parameter:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#custom-sorting

To elaborate based on the JSON you gave as example, it'd probably be far more meaningful to provide something like this to the store:

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: {
    identifier: 'id'
    items: [
        {
            id: 9999,
            name: "jhon",
            location: "newyork"
        },
        ...
    ]
}});
```

If you don't have control over the array you're being given, I suppose you could consider writing a function to convert it before feeding it to the store.